# Simplest way to access the value of text input field in html form JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, html-input

I want to access input field value as simple as possible from JavaScript.

```
<form name="F">
  <input name="searchTxt" type="text" id="searchTxt">
</form>
```

I can access the value with following method (tested on Firefox debugger):

```
document.F.searchTxt.value
```

But I found this method is a dialect from Internet Explorer (and works on most browsers for compatibility), and it is obsoleted on W3C DOM.
(reference: [Using the W3C DOM - Archive of obsolete content | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Using_Web_Standards_in_your_Web_Pages/Using_the_W3C_DOM) )

Another way I found is using `forms` and `elements` attributes with its child's name:

```
document.forms.F.elements.searchTxt.value
```

I like this method and I feel it is simple because it doesn't require any parentheses or quotes but only dots in the statement.
(reference: [Obtaining References to Forms and Form Elements in JavaScript - Dynamic Web Coding](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/references.php) )

I think the secret of this method is the `form` has its `name` (instead of or additional to `id`), so it can be accessed by its simple name.

Please tell me more simple, more stable or the best method to access the field values.

Comment: There's no best method for this, it all depends on your use case and the libraries you use. For example, with jquery its a one liner - `$("form").serializeArray()` and you get all the fields and values in a single array

Comment: thank you, yes, the best will be depended on the use cases. I am researching easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelector` to access the form's DOM element and it has all the properties that you need:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
console.log(form.elements.searchTxt.value);
```

Comment: thank you, document.querySelector() returns the first form (or matching element).

Comment: If you have several forms on the page and want to access them using this approach you can add either `id` or `class` for each form and use `document.querySelector('#form-id')` or `document.querySelector('.form-class')` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
let searchTxt= document.forms["F"]["searchTxt"].value;
```

Comment: What does this answer add to address OP's question?

Comment: @dhamkith , thank you. Do you know which is safer or same between 
```document.forms["F"]["searchTxt"]``` and 
```document.forms["F"].elements["searchTxt"]``` ?